# How to set current time on react-native-datetimepicker using react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How can I set the current time instead of **date** in dateTimePicker? I'm using this component from https://github.com/react-native-datetimepicker/datetimepicker#mode-optional and it works but I'm kind of lost trying to show the current time when the time picker shows up.

**Part of my code**

```
  const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date(1598051730000));
  const [mode, setMode] = useState('time');

  const onChange = (event, selectedDate) => {
    console.log(selectedDate)  
  };

  ...

  <DateTimePicker
    testID="dateTimePicker"
    value={date}
    mode={mode}
    is24Hour={true}
    display="default"
   onChange={onChange}
  />
```

Comment: Hi, so do you want to show current day and time, instead of August 21, 2020 18:15?

Comment: Have you tried `useState(new Date());` instead of `useState(new Date(1598051730000));`?

Comment: You are right @NadiaChibrikova thanks!